# MySQL Truncate Table Before Insert

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am creating a table in MySQL for which I only ever want  it to contain one tuple at a time. To enforce this, I am trying to create a trigger which will truncate the table each time an `INSERT` occurs. However, I am running into problems.

SQL:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `tbl_hire_truncate`    
BEFORE INSERT ON `tbl_hire`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  TRUNCATE TABLE `tbl_hire`;
END
```

Error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
```

Every example of a trigger that I've seen uses a `FOR EACH` loop, but it certainly doesn't make much sense with what I am trying to achieve.

How can I rewrite my SQL to achieve my goal?

Comment: Is that the entire definition?  I expect to see a `create trigger` somewhere.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Whoa! Copy-paste error. It's fixed now.

Comment: Do you have a delimiter statement?  That is probably the problem.

Comment: When you solvent the syntax problem, you may have a new problem, something like: `Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger.`. Check: [13.1.33 TRUNCATE TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/truncate-table.html): `Truncate operations cause an implicit commit, and so cannot be rolled back.`

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found any solutions?